# Unexpected snprintf behaviour

Tags: c++

I noticied a (to my opinion) very strange behaviour of snprintf with c++ on several platforms. Consider the following code (minimum working example which causes the observed behaviour):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char test1[512];
char test2[512];
char test3[1024];
char test4[1024];

int main()
{
    snprintf(test1, sizeof(test1), "test1");
    snprintf(test2, sizeof(test2), "test2");
    snprintf(test3, sizeof(test3), "%s %s", test1, test2);
    return 0;
}
```

When running though valgrind with --tool=exp-sgcheck, the following error is reported (for the 3rd snprintf statement):

```
==30302== Invalid read of size 1
==30302==    at 0x568E4EB: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.19.so)
==30302==    by 0x56B7608: vsnprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.19.so)
==30302==    by 0x5695209: snprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.19.so)
==30302==    by 0x4006AD: main (1.cc:12)
==30302==  Address 0x601460 expected vs actual:
==30302==  Expected: global array "test1" of size 1,024 in object with soname "NONE"
==30302==  Actual:   global array "test2" of size 512 in object with soname "NONE"
==30302==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected
```

So passing test1 as argument to the first %s leads to a read after the end of the test1 array.

This behaviour caused several page faults in a windows driver (yes I know it's static data...). Luckily the code is portable, and when ported to linux valgrind reported that error.

But to my knowledge, snprintf should terminate test1 with \0 at the 6th byte (which it does, checked that). So why causes the 3rd snprintf statement a read after the end of the test1 array? Changing the 3rd snprintf statement to

```
snprintf(test3, sizeof(test3), "%.512s %s", test1, test2);
```

solves the problem on both platforms. Compiling the code as C code (not C++) results in no error.

UPDATE: On linux (and maybe windows as well) the error only occurs, if the code is compiled with debug information included and optimizations disabled (-g -O0 for gcc).

Comment: Not that it should make a difference in this case, but the source file name is called out in the valgrind output as `1.cc`.  Is there some reason you're writing C and compiling it with a C++ compiler?

Comment: I just tested your code with `valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck` and no error was reported, what version of `valgrind` are you using and what version of `glibc`, also what is your Linux Distro?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more. e.g. your platform, compiler version, how you compile the code.

Comment: Thanks for the C/C++ suggestion, I tested a bit further and updated the question above. The error **only** happens when the code is compiled with a C++ compiler. I thought this wouldn't make any difference here as snprintf clearly is a C function, but I could have known better.

Comment: It happens with c++...

Comment: _`I thought this wouldn't make any difference here as snprintf clearly is a C function`_ I wish everyone who doesn't understand that c and c++ are different read this. And this happens because the compilers are different.

Comment: @iharob  You are not supposed to get differences like this, snprintf and raw arrays behaves the same in these 2 languages.

Comment: Oh, I know, but yet there is a difference. Is it a bug in the c++ compiler? And the point is precisely that, the compilers are very different.

Comment: Would be surprised if this is a bug in the compiler, as it is reproducible in visual studio 2012 (bluescreen and minidump) and gcc ..err.. 4.8.3. In most cases, the read should not cause any harm, except when there is no paged memory after the array.

Comment: The error doesn't happen when not passing `-g` to `gcc` i.e. without debugging symbols.

Comment: As far as I remember with vs2012 the bug also only appeard in debug mode, not in release mode.

Comment: Does it happen when you include `<cstdio>` in C++?

Comment: Also happens with <cstdio>. However it seems I can not change the data layout that a read outside of the arrays is executed, at least not with gcc. If I swap test1 and test3 declarations, the error doesn't occur. As mentioned in the original quesion, the bug was caused in a windows kernel driver, producing lots of minidumps pointing into static driver data. Then valgrind reported these errors, and after changing the snprintf the error was gone on linux and on windows. But technically the code always run ok on linux (even with the reported error), but not on windows.

Comment: I see the same problem on my system (Linux Mint 17, g++ 4.8.2, valgrind 3.10.0). I compile with `g++ -g` and then run `valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck` on the executable. **These details need to be in the question.** Also, the problem still occurs when I comment out the declaration of `test4` and the first two `snprintf` calls. (Since the objects are static, they're initialized to all zeros, i.e., empty strings.)

Comment: I updated the original question.

Comment: I've narrowed down the test case and shown the output on Linux Mint 17: https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/723cf727f4f5c1a11481. Just from the behavior I see on that system, it looks like a bug in `valgrind` -- but that doesn't explain the page faults in the Windows driver.

Answer (score 1):

Since global objects (like the arrays in your example) are 0-initialized the last snprintf should never read beyond the string's end, independent of whether the previous sprintfs copied the terminating 0 char or not. The only explanation is that the previous snprintfs copied much more than the submitted "test1" to the target `test1`, overwriting all the 0s with non-0s (no 0s would btw be unlikely with random memory).

That is very unlikely -- such an obvious bug would have been found earlier. With respect to the error in the driver I would suspect that the memory is being overwritten by a completely unrelated "process" (in a general sense, maybe another driver). For a desktop application I have no explanation why it would fail. Trying your example on Codingground  with gcc 4.8.3 was running just fine and printed the expected strings when I added a printf() at the end.

Btw, it's not surprising that the original code runs fine with optimizations enabled: Since there is no observable effect the compiler may emit just a NOP.

Comment: One day ago I would've perfectly agreed to your answer ;) But now I have some crashdumps that point exactly to the snprintf statement with a PAGE_FAULT directly after the static data section of the driver. And as mentioned before, changing the snprintf solved this problem. Also the crash happend directly after driver init, so there was nothing required to trigger this bug. But I agree that the circumstances are very complicated here, and after all it seems to be a bug in the ms c++ compiler. Sadly there is no valgrind for windows :(

Comment: gcc 4.9.x on cygwin as well as VS 2013 run the example just fine (but no valgrind on windows, so I can only just run the prog). Can you really reproduce an error in a normal user space program? EDIT: I compiled as C, re-reading your original post that was not relevant ;-) EDIT2: VS2013 as C++ also runs fine.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this bug in user space (ie. cause a crash). However in most cases, it would not trigger a crash at all, as it's very likely that paged memory follows the last declared static data. To make a suitable test case, it would be very handy to have something like valgrind to further elaborate under which conditions the invalid read access occurs, and how it can be placed in unpaged memory (honoring things like alignment and page size). But I cannot reveal the original code here, as it is a commercial product.

Comment: To be fair, I am not sure whether the 0-init rule for global data in C programs is true for drivers, too; the runtime environment is certainly different.

Comment: As a practical matter (I'm sure you have thought of it, too) at least for strings it's trivial to replace snprintf with ad-hoc code. Ist that your original use case?

Comment: Well the error doesn't occur when setting a string precision, so I used this as a fix.

Comment: I still assume that your stack (i.e. you don't write "test1" to test1 but some garbage) or the static data (i.e. "test1" in test1 gets overwritten at some point) is corrupted. Perhaps you can write string lengths to a sys log facility. Are you sure that what you write is actually what you think you write when you use the precision? You may not get the error any longer but that's just because you work around corrupt memory.

Comment: What reference do you have for memory being initialized to 0? In many cases, memory that has been previously used within the same process is not initialized by the standard libraries, for performance reasons.

Comment: @ssube: It's the C and C++ standard for global data, for the program above (objects with static storage duration are 0-initialized, 6.7.9 in C std n1570). As I said I'm unsure whether it's true for drivers. Certainly initialization would only happen at driver init, if at all, not automatically during it's life cycle (when?). But I have never written a Windows driver, so...